# Name this topological space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define the circle $S_n$, which passes through the origin by:
$$S_n := \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+\left(y-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^2=\tfrac{1}{n^2}\right\}$$
I know that the union of all $S_n$ is taken as the base space for some topological space. Can anyone remember the name and/or supply a link? I think it has the word *earrings* in the title.

Comment: I dub this topological space "Steve." Most people call it the Hawaiian earring, though.

Comment: Ha ha ha! Thanks @CameronBuie that's the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the [Hawaiian earring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring).

Comment: ...Also known as "Steve"

Comment: ...I think I prefer Steve.